# Convert JSON string to data array using javascript or c#

Tags: javascript, c#

Convert json string:

```
[
    {"Name":"Krishna","CDate":"\/Date(1515733200000)\/","Type":1},
    {"Name":"Nik","CDate":"\/Date(1525492800000)\/","Type":1},
    {"Name":"fdf","CDate":"\/Date(1514782800000)\/","Type":1},
    {"Name":"cdcf","CDate":"\/Date(1517720400000)\/","Type":1}
]
```

to:

[image]

Comment: in javascript, JSON.parse will do it - by the way, your post comes off as a demand - take the tour, learn how to ask a good question, don't demand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example JSON String

```
string data = "{ \"A\" : \"1\", \"B\" : \"2\", \"C\" : \"3\" }";
```

Deserializing it into an object that will contain each of the keys and their values

```
object yourObject = new JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(data);
```

Comment: Uhm... you're missing part of the object: the one with `Temp` and `data`